# Obtener KEY de una lista de valores dentro de un diccionario (python)

Tags: python, pandas

Tenia una función que me buscaba valores dentro de una columna y lo reemplazaba con el valor correcto , pero me encontré que tenia que hacer una función para cada marca distinta y hacer una lista para cada marca , entonces decidí hacer un diccionario en donde la key es el valor correcto y el valor son los posibles valores que puedo encontrar dentro de esa columna , entonces lo que no estoy entendiendo como hacer es la función que le aplico al valor de una celda  me lo reemplace con el valor correcto , (el cual seria la key del diccionario).

A continuación dejo un ejemplo del diccionario y los valores que tengo , como así también el resultado final :

```
marcas={
        "HP":
            ["H.P.","HEWELTT PACKARD","HEWLETT PACKARD","HEWLETT PACKARD ENT","HEWLETT PACKARD ENTE","HEWLETT PACKARD",
             "HEWLETT PACKARD,.","HEWLETT PACKARD.","HEWLETT PACKARD.,","HEWLETT PACKARD..","HP","HP DESKJET IA2135AIO",
             "HP DESKJET IA2675AIO","HP DESKJETINKADV3775","HP DJET IA2135 AIO","HP DJET INK ADV 3775","HP DJETINKADV3775AIO",
             "HP ELECTROINK","HP INC","HP LASER 107A","HP LASER 107W","HP LASER MFP 135W","HP LJ PRO M203DW","HP LJ PRO MFP M130FW",
             "HP OFFICEJET PRO6230","HP. ","HP.","HEWLLET PACKARD","HEWLETT PACKARD,","HEWLETT","HEWLET PACKARD","HPDJETINKADV3775AIO",
             "HP LJ PRO M203 DW","HP LASERJET PROM102W","HP L JET PRO M102W"],
        "SIN MARCA":
            ["S M","S MARCAS","S.M.","S/D","S/DESC","S/M","S/M.","S/MARCA","SIM MARCA","SIN   MARCA",
             "SIN IDENTIFICAR","SIN MARCA","SIN MARCA 3016000050","SIN MARCA 3016000052","SM......","SM..","....S.....M...",
             "SM.","SM","SIN MARCAS","SIN MARCA.","","..SM....",".S.........M",".S..M...",".SM","SIN  MARCAS","S...M.","S.......M."
             "S.............M","S /M","S / M"],
        "RICOH":
            ["RICOH MP9002SP","RICOH INFOPRINT","RICOH COMPANY LTD","RICOH"],
        "EPSON":
            ["EPOSN","EPSON","EPSON           0000","EPSON EXPRESSION 120","EPSON PS13","EPSPN"],
        "SINO":
            ["SINO","SINO COLOR","SINOCOLOR"],
        "GADNIC":
            ["..GADNIC..","GADNIC","GADNIC.","GADNIC.."],
        "AQX":
            ["AQX ETCH","AQX TECH","AQX TECH.","AXQ TECH","ACQ TECH"],
        "FLINT":
            ["FLINT","FLINTGROUP","FLINT INK","FLINT GROUP"],
        "SERVICOMP":
            ["SCP SERVICOMP","SCP"],
        "METTLER":
            ["METTLER","METTLER TOLEDO","METTLER/TOLEDO"],
        "EFI":
            ["EFI VUTEK GS SERIES","EFI VUTEK H2000 PRO","EFI VUTEK H2000","EFI","EFI VUTEK HS ULTRA P","EFI JETRION4000/4830","EFI VUTEK HS125 PRO",
             "EFI VUTEK","EFI VUTEK HS 125 P","EFI VUTEK HS ULTRA","EFI HS PRO XA V2","EFI SUPERRANGE","EFI VUTEK GSR SERIES","EFI VUTEK LX3 PRO","EFI REGGIANI AQUA PR",
             "EFI JETRION","EFI JETRION 4000/483","EFI 3M SUPERRANGE XF","EFI MATAN","EFI REGGIANI"]
        }
```

ese seria el diccionario de equivalencias por así decirlo 
 a continuación tengo un dataframe en el cual los valores son :

```
                 MARCA  CANTIDAD
0  EFI VUTEK GS SERIES       300
1  EFI VUTEK H2000 PRO       250
2         EFI REGGIANI      5000
3           ..GADNIC..       100
4                 H.P.        20
5               GADNIC        10
6      HEWLLET PACKARD      8000
```

el resultado final de la columna de mi df debería ser el siguiente:

```
    MARCA  CANTIDAD
0     EFI       300
1     EFI       250
2     EFI      5000
3  GADNIC       100
4      HP        20
5  GADNIC        10
6      HP      8000
```

Cualquier recomendación es bien recibida , como así también sugerencias para editar la pregunta si es necesario

intente con esta función pero me devuelve nan o listasvacias

```
def cleaner(celda):
    try:
        celda= [key  for key, value in marcas.items() if value == celda]
        celda=celda[0]
    except:
        celda=celda
    return celda

df2["MARCA"]=df2["MARCA"].apply(cleaner)
```

Comment: de esa forma estaria retornando una lista , necesito el string correspondiente (probe usando keys[0]) pero me deja todo en blanco

Comment: olvide aclarar que eso es solo un ejemplo , estoy trabajando con un dataframe que tiene 100 mil lineas y 27 columnas , no es que necesito buscar la key que corresponde a un valor x , sino una funcion que reemplace el valor de la celda por el valor limpio (la cual es la key del diccionario) , avisame si te puedo agregar mas info para que sea mas claro

Comment: pero si es un dataFrame coloca el codigo cambia con el solo decir que es pandas

Comment: agregue un edit de lo que ya intente similar a lo que me comentaste

Comment: tambien necesitamos los datos basico que tienes en el df, por lo menos 4 registros

Comment: ahora edite y agregue una muestra de lo que tengo y cual seria la salida

Comment: intenta `[key  for key, value in marcas.items() if celda in marcas[key]]`

Comment: Excelente! sirvio!!!  , esa primera parte , ahora lo que me sucede es que los valores que no estan en el diccionario los devuelve como una lista vacia (no entran nunca en el except)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104665/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-matias-ordonez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo cambiaría un poco la forma de atacar el problema ya que estas iterando en cada key del diccionario lo cual te puede dar una complejidad de O(N*M).

Si cambias la estructura de tu diccionario a:

```
marcas={
    "H.P." : "HP",
    "HEWELTT PACKARD",: "HP",
    "HEWLETT" : "HP",
    "RICOH MP9002SP" : "RICOH",
    "RICOH INFOPRINT" : "RICOH",
    "RICOH COMPANY LTD" : "RICOH",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Puedes obtener el valor que buscas de una manera mucho mas rapida (O(N)).

```
def cleaner(celda):
    # buscas el valor de la celda en el diccionario, si no lo encuentra regresas la misma celda
    celda = marcas.get(celda, celda) 

    return celda


df2["MARCA"]=df2["MARCA"].apply(cleaner)
```

Comment: Si , realmente estaba pensando en la forma de no recorrer absolutamente todos los valores del diccionario , para cada una de las celdas voy a invertir el diccionario y probar lo que me contas

Comment: SOLUCIONADO!! inverti el diccionario que tenia y funciona perfecto , muchas gracias a ambos!

Comment: sabia que existia una forma mas sencilla, pero no queria cambiar los datos de entrada del usuario